# Hydra when redirects

Tags: brute-force, hydra

I'm using Hydra and I have trouble with this command:

```
hydra 123.123.123.123 http-form-post \
    "/se/login:j_username^USER^&j_password=^PASS^&submit=Log+in:/se/invalidLogin" \
    -L /root/Desktop/users -P /root/Desktop/list`
```

*There are three passwords in the list. One is correct, the others are not.*

When the password is incorrect, the user is redirected to `/se/invalidLogin`.
How can I add this to the above, as the command right now is wrong?
It says every password is valid.

Comment: Maybe the list you are using doesn't have the correct password to any accounts.

Comment: No. There are 3 passwords in the list, one of them is correct. Hydra seems to think every password is correct.

I need to be shown how to continue when redirect is /se/invalidLogin...

Comment: See what happens if you take "&submit=Log+in" out of your command. Also, change "/se/invalidLogin" to something that's on the page text. i.e., "Bad login".

Answer (score 2):

Replace `/se/invalidLogin` with some page text that's encountered when the login is wrong.

e.g. "Incorrect password"

Hydra will check the text on the redirect target.

Comment: I did that but sadly it didn't work :-(   Also found a bug myself: j_username^USER^  is missing = , so should be j_username=^USER^